# FirebaseAuth.getInstance() crashes with "IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was trying to create a login system from my app, but it crashes when I open it. I managed to locate the bug to the line

```
mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

which makes no sense to me. Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initialize Firebase Auth
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
        // Not logged in, launch the Log In activity
        loadLogInView();
    }
}

private void loadLogInView() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LogInActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and the crash report:

```
02-20 01:04:45.137 3186-3186/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.maegner.testingfirebase, PID: 3186
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.maegner.testingfirebase/com.maegner.testingfirebase.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)..............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception can be caused by a misconfigured `google-services.json` file.  The error will occur if the `api_key` is missing.  Verify that your `google-services.json` file contains this section:

```
  "api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": "AIzaSyDkG-g8hH7T4TV7RrN23ccnRsXp12345678" //<-- your key here
    }
  ],
```

If it does not, regenerate `google-services.json`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by upgrading the dependency from

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
```

See [this](https://itnext.io/android-firebase-authentication-email-and-password-login-b06980cf864a) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have used the plugin:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Some conflicts can occur with libraries such as 'com.google.android.gms: play-services-maps: 16.0.0', and in this case the plug-in is often removed as a solution, and in the case I identified, this was the problem. Take a test without the play-services libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have you enabled auth in firebase.
Make sure that you have added auth dependency in Gradle module app.
Create an application class and add these 2 -
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);